# What folders can be safely deleted after building UE4 from source?

Tags: unreal-4

What folders, if any, can be safely deleted, after building UE4 from source?
After the build, UE4 files occupy 65 GB of disk space, which is way above comfortable for me, since I only had 72 GB free.
I would like to cut the folder down to size, say at least 25 GB.
Are there any files that are not required to use the Unreal Engine with full functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an installed build: 
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Deployment/UsinganInstalledBuild/index.html

This will output a standalone binary engine that is somehow identical to engine you would download from the launcher .

Then you can delete all the source files.